# Can an Artillerist artificer activate multiple Eldritch Cannons with the same bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, artificer, bonus-action

To my understanding, an Artillerist artificer can create an Eldritch Cannon during a battle using an action. The first one of the day doesn't require expending a spell slot.

But what about activation and movement during a battle? Can you activate and move all Eldritch Cannons using the same bonus action?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### You can't have multiple Eldritch Cannons until level 15.

The description of the [Artillerist artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#Artillerist)'s [Eldritch Cannon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#EldritchCannon-1138963) feature (*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, p. 17; emphasis mine):

> Once you create a cannon, you can't do so again until you finish a long rest or until you expend a spell slot to create one. **You can have only one cannon at a time and can't create one while your cannon is present.**

Spending a spell slot to create a cannon is how you replace it during the day if the initial free one gets destroyed. You can't just keep spending spell slots to produce more & more cannons to create an army of them.

#### At level 15, a single bonus action activates & moves both cannons.

The description of the 15th-level [Fortified Position](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#FortifiedPosition-1138966) feature says (*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, p. 18; emphasis mine):

> You can now have two cannons at the same time. You can create two with the same action (but **not the same spell slot**), and **you can activate both of them with the same bonus action**. You determine whether the cannons arc identical to each other or different. You can't create a third cannon while you have two.

Once you hit level 15 and gain the Fortified Position feature, you can have two cannons out, and a single bonus action can be used to command both of them.

Comment: Ok, at level 15, every time you create 2 cannons with the same action the first one is free and the second one expends a spell slot?

Comment: @GeorgeKaf Once per day you can create your cannon(s) for free. At levels 1-14 you get 1 cannon that way, at level 15+ you get 2 cannons. You can always spend a spell slot to replace *one* cannon, either because it was destroyed or because you want a different type of cannon.

Comment: I don't see any wording that says you can have two cannons for free, once a day. I see that you can create a single cannon for free once a day; further cannons within that day require a spell slot each. All that changes at level 15 is your max number of cannons and how many you can make in an action. It does not change the cost of making turrets.

Comment: @Lucas Fortified Position says "you can create two with the same action".

Comment: Yes, we've covered that. The rules say you can create two in the same action, but it does not say the cost is free. If you read the very next words from where you quote, it then says "but not the same spell slot"

Comment: @Lucas I believe the intent of "create two with the same action" is that you get both for free in the 1/day action, but I'll admit it's not as explicit in that regard as I would like. If they intended to tax the artificer a spell slot every day (because what good is a feature to have 2 cannons if you don't use it, cannons are the whole point of the archetype), I think they would have said that more clearly. If you strongly disagree, you're welcome to ask a new question on the topic.

Comment: My goal was to highlight the interpretation of rules for future answer viewers, and that has happened. Thanks!